# Was casting adults as teenagers more common in the past?

Tags: casting, cinema-history

I've think I've noticed that decades ago, Hollywood seemed to be more okay casting actors in their 30s as teenagers.

In *Grease,* for example, Stockard Channing was 34, Jamie Donnelly was 31, Michael Tucci  was 32 (looked like 42), Dennis Steward was 31, Annette Charles was 30, Olivia Newton-John was 30. They were all playing characters who were 17 or 18 years old.

Was this discrepancy in actor/character age more typical in decades past than now? If so, why?

Comment: http://www.collegehumor.com/post/6868573/how-old-were-these-actors-when-portraying-high-schoolers

Comment: Still seems [pretty prevalent now](http://actualteenadultteen.tumblr.com/)

Comment: @Richard  Another example is Pretty little liar, the actors/actresses who are supposed to be 17 or 18 actual ages are (31-29-29-25-28-25-25-25-27-25-26).  [Source](http://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/How-Old-Actors-Pretty-Little-Liars-35436781?stream_view=1)

Comment: I think using only one film as a basis for a theory isn't strong enough.

Comment: After some consideration, I've voted to close as "too broad". The term 'Hollywood' film encompasses over a thousand films a year (going back nearly a century) in a huge range of genres. You've also not defined what you'd consider a suitable answer (e.g. a complex regression analysis / A quote from a prominent casting Director, etc).

Comment: @Richard Just out of curiosity, do you think it is "too broad" just because of the term 'Hollywood'?

Comment: @steelerfan - That's certainly *one* of my concerns. Even assuming that someone actually keeps records of the actual age every teenaged character in every hollywood film ever made (all 100,000+ of them), does this question relate to characters over 13 or only over 17? Does it also include characters in the early 20s playing 16 year olds, for example?

Comment: It's pretty broad but I'll submit my vote for oldest-person-to-play-teenager: Roddy MacDowell, 38, plays a high school senior in "Lord, Love A Duck". 38!

Answer (score 4):

In some cases it's just plain old economics. Teenagers under 18 are under a completely different set of union rules than adult actors. They have many more restrictions including the necessity of on set tutors and far less working hours/overtime options. All in all, if producers can get away with not actually casting teenagers, they do.

Answer (score 1):

The role of teenagers in popular culture before the 90's was almost non-existent. They were not directly marketed to, nor where they prominent figures in 'grown-up' Hollywood features - meaning something that didn't involve a campy, or angst filled romp, usually involving a summer camp, or a popular hobby like roller skating, skateboarding, etc.

The advent of children's television stations, as opposed to just shows, were an invention of the mid-late 80's, and it just steamrolled from there. I graduated high school (in the USA) in 1989, and it was totally normal for adults to portray teenagers, especially in films that dealt with adult themes, such as sex, drugs, alcohol, etc. - for example, Jodie Foster's character as a prostitute in 'Taxi Driver' was not the norm.

The entire culture for those under 21 changed drastically once teens were seen as an audience with not only buying power, but also when technology advanced and they grew up with computers in school. It was simply becoming a younger, more progressive world, and as art does, it imitated life. Now, it's almost gone the other way - it's almost unheard of to see an actual person of appropriate age be in an American film - ie: in real life you would never find a police detective in their 20's, nor a high ranking government official under the age of 40.

The culture, mainly in North America, is very youth obsessed. But, again, with the advent of the internet, it has given an easier platform for pornography - which is typically a young person's domain for starring in - and, rampant consumerism, which preys upon people's normal aging as something that needs to be fixed by spending money on, the culture will continue to remain more youth-oriented, than not.

Comment: This rant does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: I tried to fix it a little. It *does* indeed provide an attempt at explaining the reasons that the question asks for.